# Scale ImageView based on properties of another ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, scale

I am trying to place an Imageview on top of another Imageview as follows:

[image: Desired Outcome]

This is the layout I use to achieve this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_logo"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|start" />
</FrameLayout>
```

This does the job of placing the logo on top of the image, but the catch here is that I should also scale the logo (the original size is around the same as the image) based on the properties of the image. More specifically, I want to render the logo at a quarter of the width of the image, have an aspect ratio of 1:1, and add 10% padding of the images' width.

At the moment, I'm just playing around with the values of layoutwidth, layoutheight, paddingLeft and paddingTop of the logo until I get the desired outcome. Is there a way to dynamically change the properties of the logo based on the properties of the image?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a [`PercentRelativeLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html) to achieve your desired layout, where your logo has 10% top and start margins, and 10% width (or whatever width percent you need). Note that the `SquareImageView` is a custom view currently at package `com.example`, and that it will ignore any height value given and will reset to the calculated width (Which is 10% of the image's width).

**Example XML:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ff0000" />

        <com.example.SquareImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="#0000ff"
            app:layout_heightPercent="10%"
            app:layout_marginStartPercent="10%"
            app:layout_marginTopPercent="10%"
            app:layout_widthPercent="10%" />


    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**SquareImageView.java :**

```
public class SquareImageView extends ImageView {
    public SquareImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredWidth()); // Snap to width
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad I could be of help.

Comment: I am encountering another problem and I was wondering if you could help me. The app:layout_marginTopPercent="10dp" property doesn't seem to work as the logo is always stuck on the top of the image, no matter what value I pass into that parameter. It might be worth mentioning that the xml represents an item in a RecyclerView, this might have something to do with margin not working. Edit: Note that app:layout_marginStartPercent="10%" works just fine, which makes it even more weird that marginTopPercent doesn't work.

Comment: I really don't know why this happens. Try adding the same code to an activity and populate the data like you do in your adapter to check whether it is a RecyclerView-related behavior or not.